# calling inline onclick method of javascript to anonymous not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code in my html file

```
<a onclick="getRestaurantTiming({{ $afternoonTiming[$j]->id}});">Hi</a>
```

I have anonymous function in restaurant.js file

```
var Restaurant = (function ($) {
    function getRestaurantTiming(id) {
        alert('hi');
    }
})(jQuery)
```

I want to call anonymous function in onclick method. Something like

```
<a onclick="Restaurant.getRestaurantTiming({{$afternoonTiming[$j]->id}});">Hi</a>
```

Please help.

Comment: Your Restaurant code is not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

You should return *this* cause you not instantiate object by new. Also function inside getRestaurantTiming should be binded to *this*.

```js
var Restaurant = (function($) {
  
  function getRestaurantTiming(id) {
    alert('hi');
  }

  this.getRestaurantTiming = getRestaurantTiming;

  return this;
  
})(jQuery);

Restaurant.getRestaurantTiming(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use it without the curly brackets.